# text to csv using awk to map matched rows to comma seperated columns

Tags: awk

If I have a text file with records separated by // and headings with single row or multi-row content e.g.

```
SOMETHING (single line content)
ATHING Lorem (single line content) 
THETHING (single line content)
THING (multi-line content)
ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
//
SOMETHING (single line content)
ATHING Lorem (single line content) 
THETHING (single line content)
THING (multi-line content)
ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
```

And I want to print: 
1) a row that matches "ATHING" and 2) a multiline row that matches start with THING until the next heading so that I end up with this output:

```
ATHING content, THING content (multi-line concatenated to single line)
ATHING content, THING content (multi-line concatenated to single line)
```

Comment: Try to look at similar questions first. Like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010200/awk-matching-patterns-from-row-based-file-and-output-as-csv?noredirect=1#comment78981788_46010200. If you're not successfull with your attempts, show us some code.

Comment: Make sure the expected output you post can be generated from the sample input you post to a) help clarify your requirements, and b) provide data we can test a potential solution using. And don't just keep repeating "thing" and "single/multi line content" all over the example - show actual things and actual content.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

Sample `testfile` contents:

```
SOMETHING (single line content)
ATHING Lorem (single line content) 
THETHING (single line content)
THING (multi-line content)
some tetx
sdsdf text
ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
//
SOMETHING (single line content)
ATHING Lorem (single line content) 
THETHING (single line content)
THING (multi-line content)
text 
text
ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
```

---

The job:

```
awk -v th="^THING" '/^ATHING/{ printf "%s,",$0 }
       $0~th{ f=1 }
       f{ if ($0~/^[A-Z]/ && $0!~th){ f=0; print "" } else printf " %s",$0; }' testfile
```

The output:

```
ATHING Lorem (single line content) , THING (multi-line content) some tetx sdsdf text
ATHING Lorem (single line content) , THING (multi-line content) text  text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN                   { OFS = ", " }

/^\/\// && line         { print line;
                          line = "";
                          getline;
                          next          }

NR > 1 && line          { line = line OFS $0 }
NR > 1 && !line         { line = $0 }

END                     { print line }
```

This `awk` script will build up each output line in `line` and output it when appropriate.

- The `BEGIN` block sets the delimiter used to concatenate the lines.
- The second block executes when a `//` delimiter is found and there's a line assembled in `line`.  It prints the line and resets the variable. It also skips over the next line of input (the `SOMETHING` input lines) and continues with the next input line after that from tho start of the script.
- With `NR > 1` we skip the initial `SOMETHING` line.  If line contains something, the current line is appended to it, otherwise we just set `line` to the current line of input.
- At the end, the line assembled for the final input block is outputted.

For the given data, this produces:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.in
ATHING Lorem (single line content), THETHING (single line content), THING (multi-line content), ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
ATHING Lorem (single line content), THETHING (single line content), THING (multi-line content), ANOTHERTHING (single line content)
```

Comment: thank you, how can i specify the rows by header name? (e.g. by "ATHING")

Comment: @gungu You will have to provide more complete input data, together with expected output.